# How to go back to the beginning of a code without ending it?

Tags: java

I want to go back to the beginning of my code in order to print multiple things and allow people to add multiple “drawings” to a picture without ending the code

Here’s my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Art {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What would you like your scene to contain?");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many " + response + " would you like?");
        int number = userInput.nextInt();

        if (response.equals("trees") || response.equals("Trees")) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What kind of trees would you like?");
            String variation = scan.nextLine();

            if (variation.equals("Pine") || variation.equals("pine")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println("    /\\");
                    System.out.println("   /  \\");
                    System.out.println("  /    \\");
                    System.out.println(" /______\\");
                    System.out.println("    []    ");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            } else if (variation.equals("oak") || variation.equals("Oak")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println(" \\  ||- \\/-");
                    System.out.println(" -\\/|| -/");
                    System.out.println("   \\||-/");
                    System.out.println("   -[]    ");
                    System.out.println("    []-   ");
                }
            } else if (variation.equals("christmas") || variation.equals("Christmas")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println("       o       ");
                    System.out.println("     .'.'.     ");
                    System.out.println("    .*.'.*.    ");
                    System.out.println("   *.'.*.'.*   ");
                    System.out.println(" .'*.'.*.'.*'. ");
                    System.out.println("*.''.*.'.*.''.*");
                    System.out.println("      [ ]      ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to add more?");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response1 = scan1.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: by adding a loop into your code. loop { yourCurrentCode(); }

Comment: I am surprised you need to ask, since you already use loops in your current code.

Comment: Also note that these 'multiple drawings' will be split onto newlines, rather than as trees appearing next to each other...  If you want that there's some more work to be done.

Comment: Also your code could benefit from use of some switch() cases

Answer (score 1):

Use a do-while loop to go inside the loop at least once.

You are asking at the end if he wants to add more, you should give the User a choice like type in 'Y' for more.
The 'Y' is here just a dummy value you can replace it with anything you want this should just be an example.

Then you compare the typed in value in the condition of your `while()`

When the value you are asking for was typed in then go ahead and loop through it again.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String response1;
   do{
    System.out.println("What would you like your scene to contain?");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many " + response + " would you like?");
        int number = userInput.nextInt();

        if (response.equals("trees") || response.equals("Trees")) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What kind of trees would you like?");
            String variation = scan.nextLine();

            if (variation.equals("Pine") || variation.equals("pine")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println("    /\\");
                    System.out.println("   /  \\");
                    System.out.println("  /    \\");
                    System.out.println(" /______\\");
                    System.out.println("    []    ");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            } else if (variation.equals("oak") || variation.equals("Oak")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println(" \\  ||- \\/-");
                    System.out.println(" -\\/|| -/");
                    System.out.println("   \\||-/");
                    System.out.println("   -[]    ");
                    System.out.println("    []-   ");
                }
            } else if (variation.equals("christmas") || variation.equals("Christmas")) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                    System.out.println("       o       ");
                    System.out.println("     .'.'.     ");
                    System.out.println("    .*.'.*.    ");
                    System.out.println("   *.'.*.'.*   ");
                    System.out.println(" .'*.'.*.'.*'. ");
                    System.out.println("*.''.*.'.*.''.*");
                    System.out.println("      [ ]      ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to add more?");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        response1 = scan1.nextLine();
   }while(response1.equals("Y"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround your code with while(true)

```
while (true)
    {
        // add your code here
    }
```

You can break the loop by using 'break;'